# JSF2 - javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException. Not working with methods

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, icefaces

when I try to render the view, browser show this error

```
01:46:11,371 GRAVE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) Error Rendering View[/index.xhtml]: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /index.xhtml @15,74 value="#{actividades.getAll}": The class 'org.pfc.controller.principal.ActividadesController' does not have the property 'getAll'.
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:111) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
```

**ActvidadController code**

```
@ManagedBean(name="actividades")
@ViewScoped public class ActividadesController implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private final static Log logger=LogFactory.getLog(ActividadesController.class);

    @ManagedProperty(value="#{actividadBO}")
    private ActividadBO actividad;



    public void setActividad(ActividadBO actividad) {
        this.actividad = actividad;
    }

    public List<Actividad> getAll(){

        logger.trace("ActividadesController.getAll");

        return actividad.getAll();
    }
}
```

**View code**

```
    <h:body>
        <ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/templates/main-template.xhtml">
            <ui:define name="content">
                <h:dataTable value="#{actividades.getAll}" var="actividad">
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText>Título</h:outputText>
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="{actividad.titulo}"></h:outputText>
                    </h:column>
                </h:dataTable>
            </ui:define>
        </ui:composition>
</h:body>
```

I use JBOSS 7 and my project has el-impl2.2.jar,el-api.1.1.jar and icefaces3 libraries.

I don´t understand why the render not working.

Any suggestions?

Kind regards.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here,

```
<h:dataTable value="#{actividades.getAll}" var="actividad">
```

Your EL expression is invalid. It's looking for a method `getGetAll()`, but you only have a `getAll()` method representing a getter for the (fictive) property `all`. The property doesn't need to exist at all (it's supposed to be `private` anyway).

So, to fix your problem, it must be

```
<h:dataTable value="#{actividades.all}" var="actividad">
```

or, if you're using EL 2.2 (but this way is not recommended)

```
<h:dataTable value="#{actividades.getAll()}" var="actividad">
```

Either way, it will call the proper `getAll()` method.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, you've by the way another design flaw in your code. A getter is invoked as many times as EL needs to resolve it. Doing business/database access job inside a getter method is a bad idea. A getter is supposed to *just* return bean properties. Rather move the DB job out to bean's (post)constructor.

```
private List<Actividad> all;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    all = actividad.getAll();
}

public List<Actividad> getAll(){
    logger.trace("ActividadesController.getAll");
    return all;
}
```

#### See also:

- [Why JSF calls getters multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090033/why-jsf-calls-getters-multiple-times)